# ValueError: X.shape[1] = 2 should be equal to 13, the number of features at training time

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning

I am trying to predict lung cancer data by using SVM document classifier using scikit-learn and I am using the following code but getting some error. I have used `matplotlib.pyplot as plt` for data plot but getting error.

Here I am using lung cancer data risk factor wise.

Input File

```
GENDER  AGE SMOKING YELLOW_FINGERS  ANXIETY PEER_PRESSURE   CHRONIC DISEASE FATIGUE     ALLERGY     WHEEZING    ALCOHOL CONSUMING   COUGHING    SHORTNESS OF BREATH SWALLOWING DIFFICULTY   CHEST PAIN  LUNG_CANCER
F   59  0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
F   63  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0
F   75  0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1
M   69  0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
M   74  1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
M   63  1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0
```

**Script SVM**

```
# Support Vector Machine (SVM)

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Vishnu/Desktop/Lung Cancer/lung_cancer.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 15].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Fitting SVM to the Training set
from sklearn.svm import SVC
classifier = SVC(kernel = 'linear', random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

# Making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

# Visualising the Training set results
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('SVM (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Lung Cancer Risk Factor')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Visualising the Test set results
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_test, y_test
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('SVM (Test set)')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Lung Cancer Risk Factor')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**Error**

```
ValueError: X.shape[1] = 2 should be equal to 13, the number of features at training time
```

In this like I getting error

```
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
         alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
```

Why I am getting error, Please suggest me something. Thank you in adavance.

**Edit_1**

SVM Test set output graph

[image: SVM Test set output graph]

SVM Training Set output graph

[image: SVM Training Set output graph]

Can anyone please let me know. Is this a correct output or not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: At which line of code does the error occur?

Comment: @ascripter, Question edited please check

Comment: Can you further elaborate what you intend to plot? [`SVC.predict`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.predict) should return +1 or -1. You seem to achieve some probability contour plot over your first two predictors.

Comment: I am plotting the prediction result as training and test

Comment: Hard to say if this is correct. Have you updated your code that generates the graph? Or a link to the original data so we can test it ourselves? Consider also asking a second question with the new problem since your original problem is solved. Would seem cleaner to me.

Comment: @ascripter, here is link of original data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DGe3ZKeoW7UsGGq-lPQZmK0_8UXK1D6I

Comment: Yes, I have updated my code and now getting graph as shown above but I am confused Is my graph is correct or not. please suggest something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regardless of the exception, I think there are several aspects to address.

1. The **exception** itself is caused because you provide only 2 variables as input to `classifier.predict` while your model is trained on 13 variables. You'll have to set the other 11 variables to some default value if you want to plot a contour over 2 of them.

   ```
   X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                        np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
   Xpred = np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()] + [np.repeat(0, X1.ravel().size) for _ in range(11)]).T
   # Xpred now has a grid for x1 and x2 and average value (0) for x3 through x13
   pred = classifier.predict(Xpred).reshape(X1.shape)   # is a matrix of 0's and 1's !
   plt.contourf(X1, X2, pred,
                alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
   ```

   This snippet will work, however it will probably not give you what you want. With some random binomial data you get a digital red-green plot like the following. The output of `SVC.predict` is a binary matrix, not probabilities.
   [image: SVM prediction (binary)]
2. You *could* plot the [`decision_function`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.decision_function) instead as prediction result which visualizes the distance to the separating hyperplane. This could be interpreted as a **risk factor**. However it's not a probability

   ```
   pred = classifier.decision_function(Xpred).reshape(X1.shape)    
   plt.contourf(X1, X2, pred,
                alpha=1.0, cmap="RdYlGn", levels=np.linspace(pred.min(), pred.max(), 100))
   ```

   [image: SVM prediction (decision function)]
3. I see another issue with your **dataset**. It seems it has 15 columns. Then I would expect the line `y = dataset.iloc[:, 15].values` to raise an `IndexError`. If it doesn't, please check the integrity of your dataset. Was it imported correctly by [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)?
4. Also you throw away the information of the first two columns, GENDER and AGE. For the gender, you could transform `F` to `0` and `M` to `1` for example and also include age into `X`:

   ```
   dataset = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Vishnu/Desktop/Lung Cancer/lung_cancer.csv')
   dataset.loc[dataset['GENDER'] == 'F', 'GENDER'] = 0
   dataset.loc[dataset['GENDER'] == 'M', 'GENDER'] = 1
   X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:14].values
   y = dataset.iloc[:, 14].values
   ```

I hope this helps. If another question should arise while working on your intended solution and you can't find an answer by your own research, feel free to ask :)

**EDIT**

Addressing your second question regarding the correctness of the scatter plot: I don't know how you made this plot, but using your code for the scatter plot, plotted on top of the decision function, I get the following (with the [lung cancer data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DGe3ZKeoW7UsGGq-lPQZmK0_8UXK1D6I/view) you provided)

[image: scatter plot]

`y` is a binary variable. That's why `np.unique(y_set)` is the same as `[0, 1]`. I don't know how you get the columnar datapoint structure with this code. I'm sorry I even don't know what you are actually trying to achieve with this plot, so I can't tell if it displays what you want it to display.

Comment: I am trying to predict the lung cancer by using lung cancer data (as shared by me) based on different risk factor. Why my graph is different as yours. can you please edit your code. Plz suggest something which can help me

Comment: I understand what you want to _predict_. I just don't understand what exactly you are trying to _visualize_. Do you intend to make a projection of your _scaled data points_ onto the plane of the first two dimensions (which are SMOKING and YELLOW_FINGERS according to your current code), grouped by lung cancer yes (red) / no (green)?

Comment: Yes - Red, No- green, (SMOKING and YELLOW_FINGERS, ...... other column are coded 0 means no, 1 means - yes) same for all risk factor.

Comment: Then you'll get by the nature of the data nothing more than the four positions where all points aggregate. I plot them with `plt.scatter(X_set[:, 0], X_set[:, 1], c=np.where(y_set==0, 'green', 'red'))`. Your `StandardScaler` will convert the ints to floats, but each dimension of your data will still only contain two distinct values. you'll always have a 13-dimensional grid of data with two levels for each dimension. Whatever you plotted that scatters the points further must be something different.

Comment: Can you please suggest the best way of visualisation of my predicted data

Comment: Please suggest me someting for the same